# How to rerender part of page after ajax submit of form in Lift (Scala)

Tags: ajax, forms, scala, lift, form-submit

this is probably a stupid question but I cannot figure out how to do it.
So I'm new to Scala/Lift and I read the ajax form chapter in http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.8.html#toc-Section-4.8 but the "RedirectTo" in the example does not seem to be very "ajaxian" to me. Often in case of submitting a form via ajax, you would just partially rerender the same page, right?
So that's what I'm trying to do and am completely failing right now.
How do I let Lift rerender just a part of the same page after I submit the form via ajax?

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Basically, what I have looks like this:

```
    <div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
    <h2>Welcome to your project!</h2>
    <div class="lift:Test">
        <div>
            <form class="lift:form.ajax">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type=text>
                    <p></p>
                    <input id="save" type="submit" value="Save">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span id="theName">Name</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

class Test {

  def render = {
    var name = ""

    def process(): JsCmd = {
      Thread.sleep(500)

      S.notice("Entered name is: %s".format(name))
      Noop
    }

    "#theName " #> "This shall be updated with the name given in the form above" & 
    "#name" #> (SHtml.text(name, name = _) ++ SHtml.hidden(process))
  }
}
```

How would I update "theName" when submitting the form?

Comment: if u have figured out how to do this, can u explain pls. I want to use ajax with lift and without comet.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://lift.la/shtmlidmemoize-simple-ajax-updating ([Example Code](https://github.com/dpp/starting_point/blob/idMemoize/src/main/scala/code/snippet/ShowMemoize.scala)). There is `SHtml.memoize` and `SHtml.idMemoize` which automatically caches the HTML code. Not sure why it is not used in this example in the Simply Lift book.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I'm still not really sure how to do that. Becasue I have two parts on my page: the form to add a new entry and a list of entries (which I would like to update after submitting the form). Basically, just like the chat example in chapter 2 of simply lift. Except I would not want to use comet stuff for that - that would seem to be a bit of overkill for what I would like to accomplish. Would you know of a bit more elaborate example going in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have a 2 step form right?  The above poster is correct.

Save your transformation in a `RequestVar`.

in your above example, the method you want to save is render, so 1st memoize the transform:

```
 private def renderTest= SHtml.memoize { render }
```

Then, you can save this memoized transformation in a RequestVar (lasts for 1 request), or maybe a `TransientRequestVar` depending on your needs.

```
 private object testTemplate extends RequestVar(renderTest)
```

When you want to replay the transform, from an ajax event - testTemplate.is.applyAgain.

I might have misunderstood the original question, b/c if you want to do a 2 step form, you don't really need the memoize.  The memoize is if something changes on your current form, and you want to update it via an ajax event, i.e. on click or on change, b/c normally the form wouldn't update unless you did an ajax submit.